# Ruby-like 'unless' for C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, if-statement

Is there any way to do something similar in C#?

ie.

```
i++ unless i > 5;
```

here is another example

```
weatherText = "Weather is good!" unless isWeatherBad
```

Comment: no. There is `if` and `?:`, but neither works like this.

Comment: I think coming up with an increment was a bad example, will add one more in case it helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What about :**

```
if (i<=5) i++;
```

---

`if (!(i>5)) i++;` would work too.

---

**Hint :** There is no `unless` exact equivalent.

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve something like this with extension methods.
For example:

```
public static class RubyExt
{
    public static void Unless(this Action action, bool condition)
    {
        if (!condition)
            action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
int i = 4;
new Action(() => i++).Unless(i < 5);
Console.WriteLine(i); // will produce 4

new Action(() => i++).Unless(i < 1);
Console.WriteLine(i); // will produce 5

var isWeatherBad = false;
var weatherText = "Weather is nice";
new Action(() => weatherText = "Weather is good!").Unless(isWeatherBad);
Console.WriteLine(weatherText);
```

Comment: Extensions always save the day.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is wrong as the Ruby `unless` does NOT loop like my idea. I answered too quickly.**

Wrong answer below

---

The closest syntactiaclly to that with the base keywords and operators would be something like

```
int x = 0;
do 
{
    x++;
} while (x < 5);
```

Comment: so the idea would be to.

[do something] unless [condition]

you can think of it as a reversed if

Comment: [yes, it is opposite `if`, but it is not a loop](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#unless_expression)

Comment: @Konstantinos: you need to review the other answers, this is wrong as I had misunderstood the ruby syntax

Comment: @xan The funny thing is that - not being anything but a newbie with Ruby myself - you got me wondering whether I was the one who got it wrong...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Yeah, I my brain only parsed the "shape" the question was looking for (condition after operation) and ran off with me! Then suddenly it started niggling at the back of my mind :).

Answer (score 0):

There' the ternary `?:`-operator:

```
i = i > 5 ? i : i + 1
//if i>5 then i, else i++
```

(Assuming the ruby code means what I think)

Comment: OK, if `unless` is a loop then that's a whole different thing... I should mention that I don't speak ruby.

Comment: This is horrible code, and it also doesn't work at all. Your code is a complicated no-op.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm aware of the fact that this is no good style. That's why I rarely use it and so I may have got it wrong (does it work now with i+1?). But it's the shortest possible "equivalent", I think.